# Cannot set VLC as default through Get Info

Tags: macos, vlc

I cannot set VLC as default.

I know about right-click → 'Get Info' but there is no drop-down to change the default so it's not possible to change it. I'm not sure why this is but I know from searching around that I'm not alone.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a file in your Finder, left click on :

[image]

Choose VLC app and check the 'always open with' box

[image]